# Match IP with a range stored in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am returning an IP and then comparing it from a range.

I am just looking at the US IP and if it falls in a range I am displaying a messge. I am getting the IP correctly but when I am trying to match it with the range I am getting a syntax error of unexpected range. How should I resolve this?

here is how my code looks like

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com", function (data) {
    var x = data.ip;
    $('body').html(x);

    var usRange = [3.0.0.0, 222.229.21.255];
    if (x >= usRange[0] && x <= usRange[1]) {
        alert('US');
    } else alert('outside US');
});
```

Here is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/cWD7W/5/)

Comment: And why do you think the built in javascript operators will work with IP adresses ?

Comment: @adeneo--block the code line number 5 through 8 and you can see your IP. I dont understand what you are saying by the way..sorry

Comment: You're missing curlybraces in the condition as well.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that `3.0.0.0` isn't a valid number in javascript, so comparing it against, well anything, is going to fail.

Comment: @adeneo--feel free to make corrections. Stackoverflow lets you do those type of things. If you have something to contribute to the question which you think would contribute to the solution feel free.-- Thanks

Comment: You see, parsing IP adresses is complicated, it's not something I'll just whip up in a minute, and it's not something you can do with javascript operators, as a number (float) can only have one decimal, and IP adresses are invalid as number, they have to be strings, and then you have to build a parser to compare them.

Comment: @adeneo--i see what you are saying

Comment: Just check if you can do it with regex

Comment: @sSaroj--looks like that might work.

Comment: why don't you just use an IP location service API that will tell you the country?

Comment: Consider http://freegeoip.net/ for geoip info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the error means, *you can't assign number with 4 decimal dots.*

```
var usRange = [3.0.0.0, 222.229.21.255]; //Not possible
```

**FYI:** The IP address returned from the `json` is **`string`**, *not a number*.

So you approach won't work.  Here check my approach,

1) Split the ip address based on `.` returned by `$.getJSON`

```
var x = data.ip.split('.');  // returns ["122", "164", "17", "211"]
```

2) Instead of using `usRange` array just *do it with simple comparison operations*.

3) You cannot compare strings with numbers, so convert those strings to numbers like

```
+x[0] //convert "122" to 122
```

Finally,

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com", function (data) {
    var x = data.ip.split('.');
    if (+x[0] >= 3 && +x[0] <= 222) {
        if (+x[1] >= 0 && +x[1] <= 229) {
            if (+x[2] >= 0 && +x[2] <= 21) {
                if (+x[3] >= 0 && +x[3] <= 255) {
                    alert("Within range");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("Is not within range");
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWD7W/11/)

Comment: @Praveen--this is exactly what I was looking for. You nailed it. All your points are very helpful. Thanks for doing this.

Comment: @soum I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @Praveen Jeganathanand  just a thought. This will exclude few ips i guess. ex 3.255.255.255. Is it fine?

Comment: @sSaroj `[3.0.0.0, 222.229.21.255]` This is OP's restriction, not be me.  However you can uplift the condition in the if statements.

Comment: Hmm.. Have to include few more ifs' in that case. :)

Comment: @sSaroj--I dont understand how you are saying that 3.255.255.255 would be excluded

Answer (score 3):

I decided to rewrite my answer here for the sake of a better method. The first method actually converts the IP addresses to integers using bit shifting and then compares the integer values. I've left the second answer as an option but I prefer the first.

**Neither of these functions will validate your IP addresses!**

## Method 1: Bit Shifting

```
/**
 * Checks if an IP address is within range of 2 other IP addresses
 * @param  {String}  ip         IP to validate
 * @param  {String}  lowerBound The lower bound of the range
 * @param  {String}  upperBound The upper bound of the range
 * @return {Boolean}            True or false
 */
function isWithinRange(ip, lowerBound, upperBound) {

  // Put all IPs into one array for iterating and split all into their own 
  // array of segments
  var ips = [ip.split('.'), lowerBound.split('.'), upperBound.split('.')];

  // Convert all IPs to ints
  for(var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {

    // Typecast all segments of all ips to ints
    for(var j = 0; j < ips[i].length; j++) {
      ips[i][j] = parseInt(ips[i][j]);
    }

    // Bit shift each segment to make it easier to compare
    ips[i] = 
      (ips[i][0] << 24) + 
      (ips[i][1] << 16) + 
      (ips[i][2] << 8) + 
      (ips[i][3]);
  }

  // Do comparisons
  if(ips[0] >= ips[1] && ips[0] <= ips[2]) return true;

  return false;
}
```

## Method 2: Plain 'Ol Logic Mess

```
/**
 * Checks if an IP address is within range of 2 other IP addresses
 * @param  {String}  ip         IP to validate
 * @param  {String}  lowerBound The lower bound of the range
 * @param  {String}  upperBound The upper bound of the range
 * @return {Boolean}            True or false
 */
function isWithinRange(ip, lowerBound, upperBound) {

  // Save us some processing time if the IP equals either the lower bound or 
  // upper bound
  if (ip === lowerBound || ip === upperBound) return true;

  // Split IPs into arrays for iterations below. Use same variables since 
  // we won't need them as strings anymore and because someone will complain 
  // about wasting memory.
  ip = ip.split('.');
  lowerBound = lowerBound.split('.');
  upperBound = upperBound.split('.');

  // A nice, classic for loop iterating over each segment in the IP address
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    // We need those segments to be converted to ints or our comparisons 
    // will not work!
    ip[i] = parseInt(ip[i]);
    lowerBound[i] = parseInt(lowerBound[i]);
    upperBound[i] = parseInt(upperBound[i]);

    // If this is our first iteration, just make sure the first segment 
    // falls within or equal to the range values
    if (i === 0) {
      if (ip[i] < lowerBound[i] || ip[i] > upperBound[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    // If the last segment was equal to the corresponding lower bound 
    // segment, make sure that the current segment is greater
    if (ip[i - 1] === lowerBound[i - 1]) {
      if (ip[i] < lowerBound[i]) return false;
    }

    // If the last segment was equal to the corresponding upper bound 
    // segment, make sure that the current segment is less than
    if (ip[i - 1] === upperBound[i - 1]) {
      if (ip[i] > upperBound[i]) return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in this script. Consider this range: 1.2.3.4 - 1.2.7.10, 1.2.6.11 will return false even though it is in the range.

Comment: Still not accurate :) Consider this range: 10.100.100.100 - 12.3.1.1. 12.2.1.1 falls in range, but your script returns false.

Comment: Alrighty then. Third time's the charm hopefully. Updated my answer again.

Comment: Added another method to my answer. Hopefully you like it and it passes your tests. :)