# checking IP range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking for IP address and if it matches with a range then I am saying it is in the US. This is the the database for the IP ranges.

```
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/googleMap/usiprange.xlsx
```

I am looking at the two extreme ends to check if the returned IP is falling within the range. From where I am checking this works fine. But is it covering all possible cases? If not how should I compensate it?

Here is the link to the working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/cWD7W/13/

And here is the link to my previous question
[Match IP with a range stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303690/match-ip-with-a-range-stored-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment30296147_20303690)

Comment: `But is it covering all possible cases?` it likely never will - geolocating IP addresses is not an exact science. That said, are you sure it is wise to do this on client side? You realize anybody could forge this check and give you a false U.S.-positive result?

Comment: @Pekka웃--I will finally do this server side. I am just trying to get the logic correct. My concern is if the logic is looking into the entire range. But yes you are right. I will make it server side